# Load a txt link in a textarea and get word count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, word-count

I have a link with text: https://process.filestackapi.com/output=format:txt/3i0kHfrRXyGHg9StS8zf
 that I want to put the content in a textarea and get number of words, so I did this in html:

```
<textarea id="dkd" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<br><br><br>
<div id="count"></div>
```

And in Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#dkd").load('https://process.filestackapi.com/output=format:txt/3i0kHfrRXyGHg9StS8zf');

        var value = $("#dkd").val();
        var count = value.split(' ').length;
        $("#count").html("Number of words: " + count);
    });
```

Getting content in the textarea is working but I obtain only "Number of words: 1", and it's a lot of text.

I would like some help.

Comment: load is more like ajax. You should try the split using callback on the 'load' function - http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put your code inside load callback

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dkd").load('https://process.filestackapi.com/output=format:txt/3i0kHfrRXyGHg9StS8zf',
            function () {
                var value = $("#dkd").val();
                var count = value.split(' ').length;
                $("#count").html("Number of words: " + count);
            }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the callback function in load. Within the callback count the amount of words in the `text area`. The callback function executes once the load has completed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#dkd").load('https://process.filestackapi.com/output=format:txt/3i0kHfrRXyGHg9StS8zf', function() {
    var value = $("#dkd").val();
    var count = value.split(' ').length;
    $("#count").html("Number of words: " + count);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="dkd" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="count"></div>
```

.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it as a callback function it is running before the text loads 
https://jsfiddle.net/kgohLty3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dkd").load('https://process.filestackapi.com/output=format:txt/3i0kHfrRXyGHg9StS8zf',
            function () {
                var value = $("#dkd").val();
                var count = value.split(' ').length;
                $("#count").html("Number of words: " + count);
            }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

load is an asynchrone function.
when you call it, your scripts proceeds. Thus you cound the words before they are there. You need to use a callback function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dkd").load('https://process.filestackapi.com/output=format:txt/3i0kHfrRXyGHg9StS8zf', function(){
            var value = $("#dkd").val();
            var count = value.split(' ').length;
            $("#count").html("Number of words: " + count);
    });    
});
```